# Ключевые слова: справедливость, совесть и правда

Tags: этимология

Слова "справедливость", "совесть" и "правда" имеют единое происхождение?

Comment: Нет. А почему вдруг? Что у них общего, кроме - частично - значения?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите вопрос, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @behemothus, я думаю, потому что от корня "_вед_" (ведать) происходит "праведный", от "праведный" - "справедливый". Также от "праведный" происходит "правда". Далее, "ведать" - > "поведать" -> "повесть" -> "весть" ->"совесть". Как то так... Найдите неверное звено в этой цепочке

Answer (score 2):

Как говорят этимологические словари, слова "правда" и "справедливый" действительно являются исторически однокоренными, они оба восходят к слову "правый" ("праведный", "праведник" тоже части этой цепочки однокоренных слов). А вот "совесть" близка по происхождению глаголу "ведать" (однокоренные: "весть", "известие", "ведьма").